# How to use a single hook to check both IPv4 and IPv6 packets in Netfilter?

Tags: c, network-programming, kernel-module, netfilter

I am currently working on a project where I need to monitor both IPv4 and IPv6 packets in Netfilter. Right now, I am able to monitor them separately by registering two different hooks:

```
nf_hook_op_1->hook = (nf_hookfn *)ipv4_packet;
nf_hook_op_1->pf = NFPROTO_IPV4;
nf_register_net_hook(&init_net, nf_hook_op_1);

nf_hook_op_2->hook = (nf_hookfn *)ipv6_packet;
nf_hook_op_2->pf = NFPROTO_IPV6;
nf_register_net_hook(&init_net, nf_hook_op_2);
```

However, I would like to know if there is a way to merge them into a single hook so that I can monitor both types of packets at the same time.I can use `sk_buf->protocol` to filter the packets based on the protocol.

I have observed that there are different `nf_hook_ops.pf` enum values such as NFPROTO_INET, NFPROTO_IPV4, NFPROTO_IPV6, NFPROTO_ARVP, and so on. But I also see that `eth_hdr(skb)->protocol` contains similar protocols. So, what is the difference between them?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you casting to `nf_hookfn *`? If `ipv4_packet` and `ipv6_packet` are functions of type `nf_hookfn` or pointers of type `nf_hookfn *`, then no cast is necessary. If they do not have one of those types, that suggests there is a problem that needs fixing.

Comment: What prevents you from registering one routine for both hooks?

Comment: Remember that IPv4 and IPv6 are separate, incompatible protocols with very different packets.

Comment: @EricPostpischil,you are correct.I removed the type casting and didn't consider registering a single routine for both hooks. I have tested it now, and it's functioning correctly. Do you have any recommendations on whether to maintain separate hooks or use a single hook?

Comment: @RonMaupin, yes they are different packets but I can use `eth_hdr(skb)->h_proto` to differentiate the protocals right?